# Why can't pandas handle decimals for plotting?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe df that contains decimals.
When trying to plot this dataframe using df.plot() it returns an error. I first need to .applymap() this to a float.

Why is this? Is decimal a special type other than float?

```
from decimal import Decimal
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

l=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    l.append(Decimal(i).quantize(Decimal('0.01')))

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
print df
df.plot() #does not work

df.applymap(lambda x:float(x)).plot() #does work
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from decimal import Decimal
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

l=[]
for i in range(0,10):
    l.append(Decimal(i).quantize(Decimal('0.01')))

df = pd.DataFrame(l)
df = df.astype('float') #  you can simply do this

df.plot()    
plt.show()
```

The original data you're trying to plot is of `object` type not numeric. You can verify that by doing `df.dtypes`

Or even better: `df = pd.DataFrame(l, dtype='float')`

Comment: I understand thanks.. Why is decimal an object in pandas/python?

Comment: It's not, without specifying the type of data, `pandas` give it `object` type because the default dtype is set to none. It's the same with strings.